# How to open a window from the command line within a Python script?

Tags: python, command-line, window, os.system

I am working on a python script to analyze astronomy images and I am trying to open a DS9 window within a python script (DS9 is a utility that allows images to be interactively viewed and analyzed). Usually I would open DS9 by going into the Linux terminal and typing:

```
>ds9 &
```

and then it would pop up in another window.

I tried to mimic this in my python script by writing the following line:

```
os.system('ds9 &')
```

When I would run the script the DS9 window would pop up but the rest of the script would not run until I closed the DS9 window. This gave me errors because the tasks that followed needed a DS9 window to be opened.

I am wondering if there is a way to open a window from within a python scripts and still have the rest of the script continue running.

Perhaps:

```
os.system('ds9 &')
```

isn't the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` module.
 `subprocess` is a newer way to spawn processes rather than using `os.spawn*()` or `os.system()`.

In your case:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["ds9"])
```

This should run **ds9** in background.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).